# Virtual or psyical location of adfs directories do not exisit in IIS or Anyfolder Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, iis, azure, adfs2.0, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Federated Authentication Server that is fully operational, Azure Synced, Office 365 Synced and local. Every part of the configuration works flawlessly. The issue that i am having is that
There is no trace of any Web Directory Files, I have looked in every location, and the virtual directories do no exist on my Federation Proxy or Federation Server.

I am trying to edit the Log in pages or create a new form. Where are these files? or how can i create them so The federation server displays the Log in pages i have created?

Answer (score 3):

You can't find them because they don't exist!

ADFS 3.0 does not use IIS (hence no pages) - it runs directly on http.sys.

You can customize it to a limited extent.

Refer: [ADFS : Customising the screen for ADFS 2012 R2 or ADFS 3.0 or ADFS 2.2](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2014/05/adfs-customising-screen-for-adfs-2012.html) .