# What is the physical path IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx page of login page of ADFS 3.0?

Tags: active-directory, adfs, adfs2.1

I'm trying to open https://someServerName.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx page physically.
I know we have powershell command to customize this page still I want to open this page from windows explore, What is the physical path IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx page of login page of ADFS 3.0?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984319/virtual-or-psyical-location-of-adfs-directories-do-not-exisit-in-iis-or-anyfolde

Answer (score 0):

I found the physical path of adfs/ls is

```
Physical Path C:\<testssl>\adfs\ls\
```